# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder : Not an entity when it is an entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entity, hibernate-criteria

I have a working application with 30 entities or so. Mainly using the CRUD repository that generates the queries automatically. Now, some of the queries are not optimized and I want to use the Entity Graph system to join tables for some of them.

So far so good, I followed a couple of tutorials and wrote the code. The only problem left is that when I run it, I receive this error:

```
Not an entity: class com.stingray.syncmanager.models.StationRoleModel
```

This is very weird because, like I said earlier, my app already use this entity. It feels to me like the entity manager or the session is not "aware" that these entities exist, like if they were in a separate "context", if that make sense.

Anyone can point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

**CustomSqlRepository.java**

```
public CustomSqlRepository(HibernateConfig hibernateConfig, EntityManager entityManager) {
    Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
    settings.put("connection.driver_class", hibernateConfig.getDriverClassName());
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", hibernateConfig.getConnectionUrl());
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", hibernateConfig.getUsername());
    settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", hibernateConfig.getPassword());
    settings.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    settings.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(settings).build();

    MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
    Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();

    sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public List<StationRoleModel> findAllByRole(RoleModel role) {
    EntityGraph<?> graph = entityManager.getEntityGraph("stationrole-entity-graph-with-station");

    try (Session session = getCurrentSession()) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        //===================================================================
        //This line crashes with "Not an entity" which doesn't make sense at all because it IS an entity...
        //===================================================================
        CriteriaQuery<StationRoleModel> criteria = builder.createQuery(StationRoleModel.class);
            Root<StationRoleModel> from = criteria.from(StationRoleModel.class);
        criteria.select(from);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(from.get("role"), role));
        TypedQuery<StationRoleModel> typed = entityManager
                    .createQuery(criteria)
                    .setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

        try {
            return typed.getResultList();
        } catch (final NoResultException nre) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        } finally {
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**StationRoleModel.java**

```
@Entity(name = "StationRoleModel")
@Table(name = "station_role")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "stationrole-entity-graph-with-station",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("station"))
public class StationRoleModel extends BaseEntity {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It feels to me like the entity manager or the session is not "aware" that these entities exist, like if they were in a separate "context", if that make sense.

That's because that is the case. You are passing in an `EntityManager` which is associated with an existing `EntityManagerFactory` and thus also `SessionFactory`, but in the constructor of your repository, you are creating a new `SessionFactory`. The management of `SessionFactory`/`Session` and `EntityManagerFactory`/`EntityManager` should be done by the container (Spring in your case), so you shouldn't mess around with building any of that. Just inject the `EntityManager` with `@Autowired` and be done.

Comment: Ok will definitely revisit this code and try this. Will approve your answer then (could take a couple of weeks!) . Thanks